# Как сделать чтобы "ссылки" добавлялись внутрь текста?

Tags: c#, winforms

Сделал кнопку для добавления "ссылок" в "richTextBox".
"Ссылки" добавляются не в текст, а сверху "richTextBox".

**Вопрос**
Как сделать чтобы "ссылки" добавлялись внутрь текста на базе текущего кода или на базе другого решения?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // link
            LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
            link.Text = "*** LINK ***";

            // link.LinkClicked
            link.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.link_LinkClicked);

            // data
            LinkLabel.Link data = new LinkLabel.Link();
            data.LinkData = @"C:\";

            // link
            link.Links.Add(data);
            link.AutoSize = true;
            link.Location =
                this.richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(this.richTextBox1.TextLength);

            // richTextBox1
            this.richTextBox1.Controls.Add(link);
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(link.Text + "   ");
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox1.TextLength;
        }

        private void link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString());
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы создаёте новый контрол, родителем которого делаете `RichTextBox`. А вам нужно работать с [RTF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). То есть забудьте про свойство `Controls`, смотрите свойство [Rtf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Подсказка: используйте какую-нибудь библиотеку для работы с этим форматом. Поищите на [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rtf). Или [вот](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98062/RTF-Document-Constructor-Library).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А как подключить библиотеку из "codeproject.com"? PS. я начинающий